# Jenkins multibranch pipeline how to automatically initialize and update submodules of a repo

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

Basically need the equivalent of

git clone  .
git submodule update --init --remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your Multibranch Pipeline Job you have an option to add **Behaviors**, one of the behaviors is **Advanced sub-modules behaviours**, there you can configure exactly what you want to do with submodules.
You will probably want to check the `Recursively update submodules` option to achieve what you want:
[image]